# MediaConvert split video into multiple chunk but in different duration length

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-media-convert

I have one video with 1 hr time.

i want to chunk in different part by specified range.

ex:

1. 0 to 10 min
2. 10 to 40 min
3. 40 to 60 min

I know it is possible by ffmpeg but i want to do this with **MediaConvert**.

here is sample for ffmpeg but same thing i want do using *MediaConvert*

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -f segment -segment_times 0,600,2400 output%d.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using Input Clipping in MediaConvert. You would need to create multiple jobs in order to get the input clipping range and outputs you desire.

In your job settings the input blocks would look something like the following.

Job 1

```
"Inputs": [
      {
        "AudioSelectors": {
          "Audio Selector 1": {
            "Offset": 0,
            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT",
            "ProgramSelection": 1
          }
        },
        "VideoSelector": {
          "ColorSpace": "FOLLOW",
          "Rotate": "DEGREE_0",
          "AlphaBehavior": "DISCARD"
        },
        "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
        "PsiControl": "USE_PSI",
        "FilterStrength": 0,
        "DeblockFilter": "DISABLED",
        "DenoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
        "InputScanType": "AUTO",
        "TimecodeSource": "ZEROBASED",
        "FileInput": "s3://bucket/media.mp4",
        "InputClippings": [
          {
            "StartTimecode": "00:00:00:00",
            "EndTimecode": "00:10:00:00"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Job 2

```
    "Inputs": [
      {
        "AudioSelectors": {
          "Audio Selector 1": {
            "Offset": 0,
            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT",
            "ProgramSelection": 1
          }
        },
        "VideoSelector": {
          "ColorSpace": "FOLLOW",
          "Rotate": "DEGREE_0",
          "AlphaBehavior": "DISCARD"
        },
        "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
        "PsiControl": "USE_PSI",
        "FilterStrength": 0,
        "DeblockFilter": "DISABLED",
        "DenoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
        "InputScanType": "AUTO",
        "TimecodeSource": "ZEROBASED",
        "FileInput": "s3://bucket/media.mp4",
        "InputClippings": [
          {
            "StartTimecode": "00:10:00:00",
            "EndTimecode": "00:40:00:00"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Job 3

```
    "Inputs": [
      {
        "AudioSelectors": {
          "Audio Selector 1": {
            "Offset": 0,
            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT",
            "ProgramSelection": 1
          }
        },
        "VideoSelector": {
          "ColorSpace": "FOLLOW",
          "Rotate": "DEGREE_0",
          "AlphaBehavior": "DISCARD"
        },
        "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
        "PsiControl": "USE_PSI",
        "FilterStrength": 0,
        "DeblockFilter": "DISABLED",
        "DenoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
        "InputScanType": "AUTO",
        "TimecodeSource": "ZEROBASED",
        "FileInput": "s3://bucket/media.mp4",
        "InputClippings": [
          {
            "StartTimecode": "00:40:00:00",
            "EndTimecode": "01:00:00:00"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Something to note here is that clipping regions are based off the timecode on the input source. In my example I set the timecode source to zerobased, this the means the service will start the timecode at 0 and tick up. You do have the option to specifying a start timecode or using embedded timecode on the file.

Note that timecode needs to be in the SMPTE syntax (HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS:FRAMES) [2]

== Documentation ==

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/assembling-multiple-inputs-and-input-clips.html

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMPTE_timecode